# Group a list of products and services

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-expressions

I'm working with a third part service of my client that is providing me a list of products and services, which is a little bit of a mess.

The list will return all of the `services` for the `product` but the `product` `repeats itself`, for example:

The **product A** has the **service A** and the **product A** also has the **service B** so, when i receive the list i will get **two products A** with **services A and B**

What i need to do is to group all of the products to get only one with all of it's services and i have done so but i'm worried about performance because i think my solution isn't the 'best' one:

```
var productsNormalized = products.Data.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new ProdutoSSO
{
    CodigoServico = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["CodigoServico"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["CodigoServico"].ToString()),
    CodigoPeca = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["CodigoPeca"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["CodigoPeca"].ToString()),
    CodigoFamilia = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["CodigoFamilia"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["CodigoFamilia"].ToString()),
    Familia = x["Familia"].ToString(),
    Servico = x["Servico"].ToString(),
    Peca = x["Peca"].ToString(),
    Hash = x["Hash"].ToString(),
    Valor = decimal.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["Valor"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["Valor"].ToString())
})
.GroupBy(x => new { x.CodigoPeca, x.CodigoFamilia, x.Familia, x.Peca })
.Select(x => new ProdutoGroup
{
    Produto = new Produto
    {
        CodigoPeca = x.Key.CodigoPeca,
        CodigoFamilia = x.Key.CodigoFamilia,
        Familia = x.Key.Familia,
        Peca = x.Key.Peca
    },
    Servicos = x.Select(y => new ProdutoServico
    {
        CodigoServico = y.CodigoServico,
        Hash = y.Hash,
        Servico = y.Servico,
        Valor = y.Valor
    }).ToList()
});
```

Is there a better way to achieve this or this is as good as it gets?

Comment: If it's working correctly, and working for acceptable time, then you don't have reasons to change it.

Comment: @tym32167 i can't fully test it for now because i don't have the full database. But as i was told we are going to work with something close to 3k requests per day and 400 products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some improvemants possible but they are rather of technical nature then about performance as I don't think you can do much about it until you have measured it either with benchmarks or a profiler.

---

> ```
> products.Data.AsEnumerable()
> ```

This looks like you are working with a `DataTable`, aren't you? If the data comes from a database then you should group it on the server.

---

> ```
> CodigoServico = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["CodigoServico"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["CodigoServico"].ToString()),
> CodigoPeca = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["CodigoPeca"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["CodigoPeca"].ToString()),
> CodigoFamilia = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["CodigoFamilia"].ToString()) ? "0" : x["CodigoFamilia"].ToString()),
> ```

You should create a helper extension or function for such lines, it's pretty ugly to repeat it so many times. Even two times is already too many.

---

> ```
> .GroupBy(x => new { x.CodigoPeca, x.CodigoFamilia, x.Familia, x.Peca })
> ```

You are grouping by the same properties as the object has that you create in the next step:

> ```
> Produto = new Produto
> {
>   CodigoPeca = x.Key.CodigoPeca,
>   CodigoFamilia = x.Key.CodigoFamilia,
>   Familia = x.Key.Familia,
>   Peca = x.Key.Peca
> },
> ```

Instead of doing this twice you should implement the `IEquatable<Produto>` interface on this object and use this instance as a key so that you only have a single `new`.

---

> ```
> Servicos = x.Select(y => new ProdutoServico
> {
>   CodigoServico = y.CodigoServico,
>   Hash = y.Hash,
>   Servico = y.Servico,
>   Valor = y.Valor
> }
> ```

You can replace this with `Servicos = x` if you use another overload of `GroupBy` and project each item right away.

Comment: I have managed to implement most of your tips but i couldn't find my way to implement the IEquatable and how to use it on the Select. Could you please provide a small example with the GroupBy overload ? I'm quite new to C#. Thanks.

Comment: @Terkhos I completely forgot your question about the `IEquatable`, sorry ;-] I'll answer with a link because I think [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatablet-you-still-must-override-objects-equals-and-gethashcode/) a nice explanation how to do it correctly.